# Http server error on windows azure platform

Tags: php, azure

I have bunch of websites running on windows azure in same region (`North Central US`). The problem is only with one website. Sometimes it gives me `HTTP Server Error (503)`. Is there anything to do with application side or it's server issue?

I have same website running on development server without any kind of error.

> What could be the possible solutions regarding this?
>
> How to check which error are there in my PHP application OR error logs?

[image]

The Error I am getting in PHP is this:

> PHP Fatal error:  Failure in Wincache[5784] free_memory: Block 0x3d8188c not in use
> in D:\home\site\wwwroot\system\libraries\Log.php on line 44

Comment: This could be something you may need to contact your server administrator. You could make sure you are publishing your code for 'Release' and not on a 'Debug' mode.

Comment: `Release` and `debug` are the options in azure platform?

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking of VS .NET in which the IDE can configure the project to Release or Debug.

Comment: If you have Logging enabled in php.ini, look at logs that are defined. Can also review IIS Logs for the 503, but it will largely just tell you when the error happened.503 suggests the Application Pool failed to be available to execute the Request. I see this a lot with our customers. Are you running pure PHP on IIS or do you have a mix of .NET and PHP on the same site? Can use .NET to get more details from App Pool and see how much memory it uses or when it last recycled.

Comment: @Twisty: I have logging enabled in `php.ini` But I think these errors are not  application related. I have enabled error logs from azure portal from diagnostics. I am running pure PHP application. I don't know anything about .NET

Comment: @Twisty: As you can see in above graph. There are bunch of errors in those 2-3 days range..

Comment: I see the graph, but it does not indicate what types of errors or what page generated them. You will need to examine your logs to determine if they are all 503 errors or not.

Comment: @Twisty: It says: `PHP Fatal error:  Failure in Wincache[5784] free_memory: Block 0x3d8188c not in use
 in D:\home\site\wwwroot\system\libraries\Log.php on line 44`

Comment: This suggests that whatever is running in `Log.php` on line 44 is exhausting all the memory allocated to PHP. I would examine this section of code an optimize it. Or consider increasing the amount of memory PHP can use.

Comment: @Twisty: It's default codeigniter framework code. I can't do anything with it. How to increase memory in PHP? because I have same website running in development server and it has no problems..

Comment: @Twisty: Right now, `memory_limit` value in php.ini file is: 128M

Comment: If it works in your dev, you need to find out what is different about your production server. They are different servers and have different configurations. You will want to review and adjust your php.ini file.

Comment: Both server configurations are same. And I also checked `memory_get_peak_usage()` in both sites. It's not more than even 1 MB.